# Increasing setSpeechRate() over 2.0 in Google TTS?

Tags: android, accessibility, text-to-speech

I went here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setSpeechRate(float).
.

Basically, it says that I can use that function to increase the speaking speed of the Google TTS voices.  Upon testing, I've found that 2.0 is the max speed, right?  So, I'm trying to figure out how I can increase that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limitation in Google tts and 2.0 is the max you could reach. but you can find another library here which can give you more flexibility.

https://www.ispeech.org/developers

Comment: Don't you think it could be overridden?

Comment: no you cannot override it. actually the side effects of changing those parameters are too many.. to get a quality output we need to use the default parameters of google  tts.

Comment: @biganesh101 Okay, that's what I was worried about.  I thought I could override it in memory, maybe.

Comment: May I also ask you: do you know if iSpeech has an offline engine for developers?

Comment: it doesn't have it. but you could write a mail and request.

Comment: @biganesh101 I'm sure they wouldn't do it.  They don't want their code stolen, I bet.

Comment: @blganeshi101 What the hell, though? It's a good idea.  Where would you write the e-mail, man?  Maybe I can get a protest going in Time Square.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 i just meant you can raise an issue with the google. or add noise to the existing issue. I'm sure someone would have raised it already.

Comment: Is this still true?  In playing around with 5.x, it seems like it's in the 3-4 range for max now.